# Power option "When plugged in" no effect

Tags: suspend, power-management, asus

A few weeks ago i installed Ubuntu on my laptop (Asus-UX501VW), but i only noticed now that the options on power option : Don't suspend when plugged in is not working, my laptop suspend whether it's on battery(with is fine) or plugged(quite annoying)

Does someone already had this problem?

Thanks !

edit : dunno if it's important but i have tlp installed

Comment: How are you suspending? (power button, menu option or close lid). Is laptop plugged into HDMI monitor or docked? What does `tlp` do?